# Service Mode "Menu not Exist" Android 4.1.2

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, 4.1-jelly-bean

I am having little issue here. I have accessed the Service Mode via this no: *#197328640# 
Then i am choosing options as follow
[1] Debug Screen
[8] Phone control
[6] Network lock
 
When i press option 6 for network lock i am prompted again with the same screen which shows again same option so i choose [6] Network lock again and in this menu there should be 3 things showing. However what i see is only 
"Menu not Exist" 
Press Back Key 
Current Command s 1866 
 
and that's it. There are options from this menu missing and i don't know why?

Comment: Perhaps, there's no network lock, i.e not tied to a carrier's network?

Comment: @t0mm13b So basically the menu is not showing because there is no sim lock ?. However when i put sim card its not read?

Comment: What made you think "*there should be 3 things showing*" when choosing option 6? Why are you worried about "*options from this menu missing and i don't know why*"? Perhaps its different CSC code not match with your network carrier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to revert back to Jellybean 4.1.1 to get the extra options under (6)NETWORK LOCK as far as I'm aware.

Like you said there should be 3 other menu options under (6)NETWORK LOCK and they should appear after reverting back to 4.1.1.

You will need the 4.1.1 firmware for your current carrier and Phone model and (Odin) to flash the firmware.

Make sure you save the original firmware first, so if anything goes wrong with the firmware flash, you can revert back to the original firmware.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

The ServiceMenu (SM) is actually part of the modem firmware and what you see is the ServiceMode java wrapper. Thus it is very dependent on the ROM (FW) you're using and whether or not it is stock or custom. In addition the phone manufactures constantly like to change SM access codes, to prevent user from using it. In any case, there is absolutley no need to revert anything as hugoboss says, you just have to figure out how to find it. Lately you may also have to enable certain files in the /efs/ directory (requiring root).